# Issues understanding Vim's regex engine

Tags: regex, vim, syntax, substitution, prettify

I am trying to set up a script for the conceal feature to prettify strings in Python. This worked fine so far for single word substitutions. But now I would like to replace "not in" with "∉". I tried this:

```
syntax match pyOperator "not in" conceal cchar=∉
```

But that does not match anything and I don't see why not. e.g.

`x not in l` stays `x not in l`

However

```
syntax match pyOperator " not in " conceal cchar=∉
```

works. But I want the former version, as this one makes

`x not in l` to `x∉l`, hiding the spaces.

Why does the second version work and the first does not and how can I make it work?

btw. I also tried other variants, such as

```
syntax match pyOperator "\s\+not\s\+in\s\+'" conceal cchar=∉
```

That one does not work t all either, which also puzzles me, as t is a superset of the second version.

Comment: That is odd. Your first command works for me (OSX NeoVim 0.3.1, Linux Vim 7.4), obviously as long as `set cole=2`. Can you try with `vim -u NONE` to make sure none of your other settings are interfering?

Comment: Never mind - it doesn't work specifically in Python files. So the command itself is fine, but there's another syntax item that's blocking it.

Comment: @Amadan I used this as the base for my file, if that helps: https://github.com/khzaw/vim-conceal/blob/master/after/syntax/python.vim

Comment: Seems like `syntax keyword pythonOperator not` is taking precedence, and making it impossible to match `not in` at the same place. This is why putting a space in front makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is being blocked by the `syntax keyword pythonOperator and in is or not` definition, which seems to take precedence over `syntax match` (and doesn't allow for overlap). So we'll clear out that definition, and replace it with an equivalent `syntax match` one.

```
" ~/.vim/after/syntax/python.vim
syn clear pythonOperator
syn match pythonOperator /and\|is\|or\|not/
syn match pythonOperator /not in/ conceal cchar=∉
syn match pythonOperator /in/ conceal cchar=∈
```

I also changed your `pyOperator` to the standard `pythonOperator`; one reason is that it's already there (for `in`, `and`, `is`, `or` and `not`, as seen above); the other reason (from `:help 44.2`):

> By convention, each group name is prefixed by the filetype for the language being defined. [...] In a syntax file for "csh" scripts the name "cshType" would be used.  Thus the prefix is equal to the value of 'filetype'.

Comment: I see! Thanks a lot. Do you know any good general tutorial on defining custom syntax highlighting and concealment?

Comment: No idea, sorry. About Vim, I'm almost exclusively relying on `:help`; if that fails (and it's not common), then Google and random smart people on the Internet. I don't know any resource that would consistently outperform Vim's `:help`. In this case, `:help :syn-match`, `:help :syn-keyword`, `:help :syn-clear`, `:help pattern` and `:help /\|` should be useful.